# Global variable not working or something like that... discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

hey so i recently started making a discord bot. Everything went fine, i switched to cogs bla bla yea and now im trying to make a Toggle-able anti ad command. Im using a global variable to make it toggle. The code is:

```
    bruh = 'off'
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        global bruh
        if "discord.gg" in message.content.lower():
            if bruh == 'on':
                await message.delete()
                await message.channel.send("Don't advertise your server!")


    @commands.command()
    async def anti_add(self, ctx):
        if bruh == 'off':
            bruh = 'on'
            await ctx.send('Ads Detector has been Enabled.')
            return bruh

        else:
            bruh = 'off'
            await ctx.send('Ads Detector has been Disabled.')
            return bruh
```

as im looking theres no reason for it not to work but it does this
https://prnt.sc/1sozw7t
...it says `"bruh" is not defined Pylance (reportUndefinedVariable)` when i hover over the bruh in `if bruh == 'off:` or `if bruh == 'on'`
if anyone could help i would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Reference attributes in a class with `self`, not as `global`s.

Answer (score 1):

in the second function use global once again, changing it to:

```
@commands.command()
async def anti_add(self, ctx):
    global bruh
    if bruh == 'off':
        bruh = 'on'
        await ctx.send('Ads Detector has been Enabled.')
        return bruh

    else:
        bruh = 'off'
        await ctx.send('Ads Detector has been Disabled.')
        return bruh
```

Comment: well that only fixed the on message event... https://prnt.sc/1sp0zfm

Comment: if `bruh` is inside a class, it might be `this.bruh` instead of bruh as a global variable.